# ColdFusion JSON return in a specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, coldfusion

I'm trying to return data from database into jQuery based charts called HighCharts with no luck so far.

My cfquery returns two columns - DateOnly and total
If I use the following code, where I manually type in 7 dates, it works perfectly.

```
<cfset response = serializeJSON([
        [tmz.DateOnly[1],tmz.total[1]],
        [tmz.DateOnly[2],tmz.total[2]],
        [tmz.DateOnly[3],tmz.total[3]],
        [tmz.DateOnly[4],tmz.total[4]],
        [tmz.DateOnly[5],tmz.total[5]],
        [tmz.DateOnly[6],tmz.total[6]],
        [tmz.DateOnly[7],tmz.total[7]]]) />
    <cfoutput>#response#</cfoutput>
```

However, this way I am limited to the seven days and the length of the list cannot be expanded dynamically. 
Is there a way to convert cfquery into this type of list that would get accepted by javascript charts?

BTW, this is just one of the different attempts that I've tried, that did not work:

```
<cfset a = ArrayNew(1)>
    <cfoutput query="tmz">
        <cfset b = ArrayNew(1)>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(b,DateOnly)>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(b,total)>
        <cfset b = Arraytolist(b,",")>
        <cfset a[currentrow] = b>
    </cfoutput>
    <cfset b = "">
    <cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(a)#" index="i">
        <cfset b = b & "["&a[i]&"],">
    </cfloop>
<cfset response = serializeJSON(b)>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<cfset a = []>
<cfloop query="tmz">
  <cfset row = [tmz.dateOnly, tmz.total]>
  <cfset arrayAppend(a, row)>
</cfloop>
<cfset response = serializeJSON(a)>
```